# Extra Pieces for Lego Gadgets Book

Tags: gears

My son is having a lot of fun with the [Lego Gadget set](https://brickset.com/sets/ISBN9781338219630-1/LEGO-Gadgets) (book and bricks), but he can only build one thing at a time, and would love to have a lot more of the types of Lego bricks that came with the Gadget set. I looked on the Lego website in the "Pick a Brick" section, and wasn't able to find these bricks. Does anyone know where I can find extra Lego Gadget bricks without having to buy more of the full book/bricks set? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Rebrickable has [inventory](https://rebrickable.com/sets/9781338219630-1/gadgets/#parts) of elements included with this book. This website has also an options to add these elements to wanted list for Bricklink as well as BrickOw. Each element has links to both websites (Bricklink and BrickOwl) so use the one you prefer to acquire elements you actually need.

Once you know the element you need you could also buy them directly from LEGO via "Bricks & Pieces" found on [LEGO Support page](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/service/replacementparts). Although it is a bit slightly more complicated since book doesn't have a set number and you have to look up each element individually.

Answer (score 3):

You could buy extra parts on [Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/main.page) or [Brickowl](https://www.brickowl.com/)

for example

- [Technic, Liftarm](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=137)
- [Technic, Brick](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=135)
- [Technic, Gear](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=136)

Answer (score 2):

[BrickLink!](https://www.bricklink.com/)

Unfortunately, BrickLink doesn't currently list an inventory of exactly what pieces are included with that book. So you'll have to search for **Technic liftarm** or **Technic gear** and the like separately.

If you let us know what pieces you are particularly in need of, we can help create a wish list, which will allow you to find the cheapest store(s) (or perhaps the store(s) near you) with all those pieces.